# Constructor not getting called

Tags: c++, stdlist

I am making an array of 4 std::list. But when I try to access the array's first list's first A object and call the callMe() method on it I get a weird output.

Now 2 things could have happened:

1. Either the list was empty.
2. An A object was created when I tried to access the first element of the first list((*(arrayOflistOfA[0].begin()))).

Details of the above cases:

1. If no A object was created then I should have got an exception. But I didn't get any exception so I am assuming that an A object was created.
2. So if an A object was indeed created, then the constructor should have been called.

What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
        x=20;
    }
    void callMe();
private:
    int x;
};

void A::callMe() {
    cout<<"Value of x = "<<x<<endl;
}

int main() {
    const int size = 4;
    list<A>* arrayOflistOfA = new list<A>[size];
    (*(arrayOflistOfA[0].begin())).callMe();
}
```

The output is:

```
Value of x = 0
```

but the output should have been:

```
Constructor called
Value of x = 20
```

Comment: The same thing would happen if you simply created an object of type `list<A>` and tried to access it’s nonexistent first element. The behavior is undefined. It is not required to throw an exception.

Comment: You're lucky to see any output, since the program invokes undefined behavior.  You're trying to dereference an invalid iterator (`begin()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If no `A` object was created then I should have got an exception.

Not true.

> But I didn't get any exception so I am assuming that an A object was created.

Don't *assume*. **Find out.** Go to some documentation for [`begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin) and for iterators and discover that you do not get an exception, [you get UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end).

> An A object was created when I tried to access the first element of the first list(`(*(arrayOflistOfA[0].begin()))`). [And] if an A object was indeed created, then the constructor should have been called.

That's right. Clearly you have no elements in the list.

And we know that, because there is no code in your program that [adds elements to the list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back).

Also you should not dynamically allocate containers unless you really, really need to (I've never found a need to).

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Your explanation was indeed awesome! Coming from Java background, it takes time to digest undefined behaviour. In Java its usually exception or compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually populating the list with any values. I tested the below code and include a commented explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A();
    void callMe();
private:
    int x = 0;
};

A::A()
{
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
    x = 20;
}

void A::callMe() {
    cout << "Value of x = " << x << endl;
}

int main() {
    const int size = 4;
    list<A>* arrayOflistOfA = new list<A>[size];
    cout << arrayOflistOfA->size() << endl; // As you can see, size is 0 here - you created a list of nulls.

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arrayOflistOfA->push_back(A());
    }

    // The below code demonstrates how to loop through the array once it's populated.
    list<A>::iterator it;
    for (auto& a : *arrayOflistOfA)
    {
        a.callMe();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First I think you misunderstood arrayOflistOfA as one single list. Its an array of lists. Secondly you are creating A objects and pushing it into the first list in the array. I didn't even do that. So if according to you I created a list of nulls, then I should have got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or some other exception.

Comment: You may be right. When I tried to compile your code out of the box, I do encounter a 'cannot dereference end list iterator' error. That's why I modified it the way I did.  I suppose this is different than EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but I'm not sure. I appreciate you taking the time to explain to me what I misunderstood, I'm still in SDEV-340 (c++2) so it is by no means my strongest language. That said, this code looks to me like you're creating a list of lists? Where does the array come from? Either way, .size() is evaluating to 0 in your provided code. Is this meant to be undefined as the others said?

Comment: First of all sorry for replying back so late. No the size is not meant to be zero. I was debugging something else in one of my projects where I encountered this. Anyways as others mentioned, when I ran it through some other compilers, I did get exception. Thanks for answering. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question. Firstly I tried to run this code on my mac with GNU C++ compiler but when I ran the same code on an iPhone simulator it crashed. So as @PaulMcKenzie mentioned, I was indeed trying to dereference an invalid iterator.